# Can't get Java to assign a value to a variable using if statement

Tags: java

This code is supposed to get a letter input from the user and then assign a value to the letter based on how many points it's worth. This is my first part working in Java, and for some reason I can't get the `if` statement to assign the variable anything.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LetterValues {

public static void main(String args[]){

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String letterInput1, letterInput2, letterInput3, letterInput4;
    int firstLetter = 0, secondLetter = 0, thirdLetter = 0, fourthLetter = 0;

    // Asks for first input letter
    System.out.print("What is your first letter?  ");

    // Reads the first input letter
    letterInput1 = scanner.next();

    // Converts the first letter to upper case, prints out to check
    System.out.println(letterInput1.toUpperCase());

    // Prints out first letter to check
    System.out.println(letterInput1);

    // Assigns a value to the firstLetter int based on the value of letterInput1
    if ( (letterInput1 == "A") || (letterInput1 == "E") )
    {
        firstLetter = 1;
    }
    else if ( (letterInput1 == "D") || (letterInput1 == "R") )
    {
        firstLetter = 2;
    }
    else if ( (letterInput1 == "B") || (letterInput1 == "M") )
    {
        firstLetter = 3;
    }
    else if ( (letterInput1 == "V") || (letterInput1 == "Y") )
    {
        firstLetter = 4;
    }
    else if ( (letterInput1 == "J") || (letterInput1 == "X") )
    {
        firstLetter = 8;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Error.");
    }

    System.out.println(firstLetter);
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
    What is your first letter?  A //<--input
    A
    A
    Error.
    0
    What is your second letter?
```

Comment: Don't compare content of Strings using `== `. Use `equals()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `equals()` instead of `==` for comparing `Strings`

Reason

`equals()` method is present in the `java.lang.Object` class and it is expected to check for the equivalence of the state of objects!. That means, the contents of the objects. Whereas the `==` operator is expected to check the actual object instances are same or not.

*Example*

Consider two different reference variables `str1` and `str2`

```
str1 = new String("abc");
str2 = new String("abc");
```

if you use the `equals()`

```
System.out.println((str1.equals(str2))?"TRUE":"FALSE");
```

You will get the output as `TRUE`

if you use `==`

```
 System.out.println((str1==str2)?"TRUE":"FALSE");
```

Now you will get the `FALSE` as output because both `str1` and `str2` are pointing to two different objects even though both of them share the same string content. It is because of `new String()` everytime a new object is created.

Comment: Also, if the case doesn't matter, you can use .equalsIgnoreCase

Answer (score 2):

Use `equals()` to compare Strings:

```
"A".equals(letterInput1)
```